# How to draw bezierPath inside NSCollectionView?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa

I have sub-classed `NSCollectionView` to listen to mouse down and mouse event. I want to draw a line whenever mouse is clicked inside collection view.

This is my drawing code block.

```
 public  func drawLine() {

    //// Bezier Drawing
    let bezierPath = NSBezierPath()
    bezierPath.move(to: NSMakePoint(50.0, 60.0))
    bezierPath.line(to: NSMakePoint(65.5, 72.5))
    bezierPath.line(to: NSMakePoint(65.5, 93.5))
    bezierPath.line(to: NSMakePoint(97.5, 87.5))
    bezierPath.line(to: NSMakePoint(97.5, 56.5))
    NSColor.black.setStroke()
    bezierPath.lineWidth = 10
    bezierPath.stroke()
}
```

Inside `NSCollectionView` Sub-Class I call this method in `draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)`, it correctly shows line when app loads up. But to make it draw only when mouse is clicked, I moved it to `mouseDown(with event: NSEvent)` method:

```
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    func drawLine()
}
```

**But when I mouse click on the collection view, I get following error:**

> : CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   : CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

My aim is to draw line from center of collectionViewItem to another item on mouse click, for that I have subclassed  `NSCollectionViewItem` and added a custom `NSView` to `addTrackingArea()`. I have set a delegate which passes the current selected item.

I need help to know where should I put my drawing code inside `NSCollectionView` to not get error like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep,

You cannot do as such.

What you will want to do is :

- Add in your class a boolean that you will pass to **true** in `mouseDown:` and to **false** in `mouseUp:`
- In your `draw:` method, check for that bool to knwow if you are to draw the line or not
- In `mouseUp:` and `mouseDown:`, after setting the boolean, call `self.setNeedDisplay()` (that will prepare a context for you and call draw automatically.)

Point is: You cannot call `draw:` on your own. When you are drawing, you are drawing inside a Graphic Context, and it has to be laid out for you.